# "Of course not" or "of course no"?

Tags: expressions

I'm not a native English speaker, and I've heard this from a teacher of mine who is not a native speaker either. Is it correct to say "Of course no"?

Comment: *Of course no* person would think that "*Of course not*" is the only possible response.  In other words, we need more context to be able to answer- please edit your question and add details, especially what was the question your friend was responding to?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context. "of course not/course not" is used to emphasize that you are saying 'no' to something. This is a widely accepted use case for stating denial over "of course no". I'm not even sure about the usage of "of course no" in fact.

Comment: Of course no usually pops up in conversations that ask about "Did you really say that? Have you seriously answered with no?" "Of course no!"

I haven't seen it in usage in a very long while now.

Comment: I think "of course not" will still convey the same meaning here. The usage is all about convenience and you are right its been obsolete for a while now.

Comment: Meaning? Absolutely agree on that account. Poor/emphasized choice of words? Definitely, the emphasis on a No can be important in some conversations, although a tad bit pointless - childish arguing with fluid rules for example.
(English is expressive and a huge miasma, mess of rules and words from everywhere. This is why, even if being obsolete, the Of course no format can live on.)

Comment: "Of course not" is the normal negative form of "of course."  You'd have to think hard and stretch the imagination to find a way to use "of course no."  You could come up with something, but that would still not be the normal way of saying "of course" in the negative.  No need to explain your context.

Answer (score 1):

"Of course no" cannot be used to express that your answer is clearly a "No". Perhaps we can consider the case of "True" (or "False") as an analogy? "True" would be a valid and complete answer to a question. Yet we would not say "Of course true". "True, of course" would be acceptable, and so is "No, of course".

However, both "No, of course" and "Of course no" combine a (potentially complete) affirmative answer and a (potentially complete) negative answer in the same sentence, which is quite disfluent. You may be able to avoid confusion by stressing either part in speech, but obviously not in writing.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, no one could ever come up with a way to use 'of course, no' in a sentence. Oh, wait.

The phrase 'Of course, no' can be correct. It is best used before a noun or a verb in a sentence.
     Of course no, may have several correct uses. 
     Of course, no amount of death would end his suffering.
     Of course, no drunkard would do that.
     Of course, no man can fly.

'Of course, no' may be best served in creative writing. The phrase does well in providing mood to a seemingly obvious point.

Some additional points to remember, 'Of course, not' is a standard reply in American English. Whereas, 'Of course, no' serves a narrative purpose. Both phrases require additional context.

An example of correct usage in dialog, "Of course, no more!" Daren spat as he spoke.

Comment: Clever. :) While *I see what you did there*, because answers on this site try to be helpful and comprehensive to everyone, it would help to explain what you just did, why it works, and why another version of that (like "of course no") by itself does not.

Comment: Point taken. :) I added content to make my comment a bit more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

'Of course no' could be considered correct, but awkward in normal everyday American English. 
The most common, usual phrase is, 'Of course not.'
It implies 'clearly not', or 'obviously not.'
However, if you were to ask someone, "Did you mean to say no?" They could reply, "Of course, No!" This implies 'clearly I meant to say no.'
In Portuguese 'of course not' would be translated as 'Claro que nao,' meaning 'clearly no.' But when translated back to English it is 'Of course not.'